# Whats your move on this hand?(KK) High Level Table

Tags: texas-hold-em, cash-game, hand-history, live

## £10/20NL DeepStack

## Player Reads

- Seat 1 fish around 8K stack LAG
- Seat 2 high lvl player 20K stack TAG
- Seat 3 ( Hero ) 16K stack LAG
- Seat 4 Small Roller champion 10K stack TIGHT
- Seat 5 Big Tournament Champion 34K stack - No read
- Seat 6 VILLAIN - Pro online player & successful tournament player 18K - - Skilled LAG
- Seat 7 Shark cash game player only 40K stack - Skilled TAG
- Seat 8 Fish 7K

Button on me.
Small 10
Big 20
Villain straddle 200,
Fold to fish who calls 200(seat 1)

Folds to me I look at K♣K♥
I raise to 650,
Folds to Villain flats 450, everyone else folds.

## Flop

Pot (1530)

7♠8♣J♥

Villain donk bets 2200 and has 15,850 behind.

Action on us!

## First Update - Next

I put him on a weaker hand after that bet and I raised to 6,400

He immediately jammed on me, what do we do now, can I fold here?

## Last Update - Result

> Folded, V shows 88 for the middle set

Comment: What happened afterwards? You folded?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans i'll post what happens after I get a few responses, I don't want to spoil it (if i get a few responses rather**)

Comment: Very interesting question. I have bad internet here. But will post an answer latest in one week!

Comment: What was the outcome of the hand?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Folded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it feels like the flat pre is likely to be a mid pair, broadway or suited connectors, the donk postflop is confusing makes me lead to the conclusion of weakness, because that range hes either on a draw or hes set mined and hit.

I'm inclined to call, will update this if you post more information on what happened next.

## UPDATE

I dont think you can fold now. If you think he has any bluffs here I think you have to call.

You also have good equity against two pairs. Against a set or straight you are pretty dead.

But you have almost half of your stack in there already.

I'm going to make a crying call.... wishfully hoping for something like j10...... realistically being alright with something like 78........but wholeheartedly expecting something like 77.

tough spot but I think it's a call now.

Answer (score 2):

Over-bet the pot here is just strange. If they made a set or straight it seems like villain would check.

Seems like AJs they want to protect. Or they totally missed and it is a bluff.

Problem you have is A, J, T, 9, 7, and 8 are all bad cards for you.

I would bet like 6000 and be happy to just take the pot. If villain jams back then yikes.  If you have a solid bankroll then I think you need to call.

Comment: added what happened next

Answer (score 2):

The main thing that concerns me about this hand is the straddle -> flat call that the villain did pre flop. Because he is a LAG player, this makes his range extremely wide. this range could include hands that beat Kings like 78s, j8s, j7s.

Keeping this in mind, I think that the best play here is to simply call as hero with the intention of calling on future streets. Bad cards could come up on the turn and river, but I think calling is the best play. The donk bet is screaming to be raised, and because villain is loose, he could easily 3-bet putting hero in a tough spot.

***After Update***

The jam by villain here puts hero in a tough spot as stated above, his hand is very polarized (meaning he either has nothing or he beats kings). I think that the best play is to fold here, he could be bluff jamming with nothing but the odds to find out are not good especially since his stack is about the same size as hero's.

Comment: added what happened next

Answer (score 1):

Pre-flop sizing looks very good. Perhaps make it a little larger like 700-750, but since the fish is so short and you are on the button, I understand and agree with your sizing.

On the flop my gut tells me to call. No way raising is good being this incredibly deep. Folding seems too weak. But let's analyze this spot.

You are getting 1.7 : 1. GTO wise you should fold 59%, or call 41% of your range. Is villain too wide or too tight betting here? It is hard to say. He has a slight range advantage, so if villain is indeed a good player he might pick up on this and start leading. He is sizing up two ~80% bets to get all the chips in, of course he might not do this. But he is probably going to be very aggressive in this spot, maybe too aggressive. Because of this I'd advice to continue with perhaps a bit less than 41%, say 30-40%. Folding more would be way too exploitable. Let's see where your kings are at.

I'm rougly guessing here. But it is just to give you an idea. I think your range looks like this: 66+, A5s, AJo+, KTs+, KQo, QTs+, JTs, T9s, 98s, 87s. This is a total 174 combinations. You should continue with around 60 combinations. Hands that are better than kings: T9s, JJ, 88, 77, AA, arguably AJ. These are 31 combinations. You need at least around 29 more combinations, and you'd be already on the tight side. Include KK, QQ, KJs, JTs, maybe 98s, QTs with a backdoor flush draw. I'd fold TT and 99 since they block too many bluffs.

Calling with this entire range and not raising anything seems mandatory. You are in position, very deepstacked and your opponent is representing a very polarized range. Raising will not accomplish anything for you, except lose your stack.

Note: don't assume too quickly that the donk lead is weak or strong. He is a good player, so I assumed him to be balanced. Either way he is polarizing himself, so I wouldn't raise. If you think he is stronger or weaker call less and more combinations respectively.

Update:

So he shoves for almost pot. You need around 33% equity. GTO wise you should fold around 50% of your range.

I think you are overplaying kings here. I don't think you can raise for value. But if you raise kings, you can raise aces, sets, a straight. Kings are not in the top 50% of your range. You don't have to call and I think you shouldn't. I think you are always going to be up against a set or a straight. Villain would have folded his bluffs to your raise, he only has strong hands. He wouldn't do this with queens. You are nearly always beat. You can avoid the spot by not raising in the first place, but definitely fold to a jam.

I am guessing you paid it off and he showed you a set or a straight. Curious to hear what happened though.

Comment: added what happened next

Answer (score 1):

Fish called, and a LAG (Hero) Raised. Now to a cash player, I would have done that pretty light to isolate the Fish. I guess the Villian (Good player) probably sensed that. He would have called you light because he thought you raised light, makes sense?

I would say any suited connector, pairs, AJ+ and some KQ, KJ and maybe even suited Ax (depending on how "loose" your image was and how light he's willing to call you.

Donk bets aren't strong. He will get at least one half pot C-Bet out of you if he has a decent hand, I think he's donking with a semi-bluff (a pair with straight draw like JT/98) or "decent" made hand like AJ/KJ.

In your situation, the reraise all-in is weak and CONTAIN ENOUGH BLUFFS that you have to call. Against his potential range, a call will almost always be correct given that you beat so many made hands and draws and bluffs. He could even think he's ahead with QQ (rare, because he should reraise preflop against a light raiser).

Overall, a call is correct here.